# Holding UIPIcker pauses all app timers

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, nstimer

i noticed that when i hold UIPicker on selection, than all my timers pauses.

I have global timer like clock which is executed every second. However when i hold picker it's pauses all timers in app stops.

Maybe some one had this problem and have a solution ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your timer should be running regardless of what happens in your UI, you should be running it on a background thread.

Of course, the timer creates its own background process to do the counting. But if you created it on the main thread then maybe the callback selector would be blocked if the UI is blocked, as is the case when holding a `UIPickerView`.

Just start your timer on a global queue and message the UI on the main queue.